# Make mobile menu show all the menu items/contents

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've been dealing with this mobile menu since last night. I can't make it show infront of the next section. It is showing but cut off. The next section is covering it.

Here is the site. "http://www.nikkibascon.com"

I tried z-index but no luck at all.

[image]

Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons. One of them is height of parent element. Does it have:

```
min-height:100%;
```

But when You use this, parents of element that have min-height:100%; must have height:100%;